# Is "The method is to view ... and then exploit ..." correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am unsure of if it is correct to write "The method is to view ... and then exploit ...".

The problem is it seems to me that I should write instead "The methods are to view ... and then to exploit ...", but this sentence sounds more weird to me than the first sentence.

Comment: Wierd... not to mention spooky! :) I suppose the decision is based on what the rest of the sentence will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method can include several steps, so it's okay to write

> The method is to view the system in its real-life condition and then exploit its design flaws in order to test its stability.

If you view these two processes as separate methods, then indeed you would have to mark it in your text somehow:

> There are two different methods used to achieve this. One method is to view the system in its real-life condition. The other is to exploit its vulnerabilities in a model. We will use the first method, then the second, then compare the results.